# how do i make unity 5.x suport c# 5 or 6?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use the keyword “**asyn**” in C# script of my visual studio 2015 unity 5.4 project. The compiler shows the following message.

> Feature asyn function is not available in C# 4.

I want to know whether the unity 5.4 support C# 5? And if support, how should I do?
ps.I can't find the **build** option in the property page of unity project on my VS2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't do it officially, because Unity is working on an old mono
https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/upgrade-to-mono-30

Look at this method: https://bitbucket.org/alexzzzz/unity-c-5.0-and-6.0-integration/overview